# Concentration bounds for martingales with adaptive Gaussian steps

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration, gaussian, martingales

Consider the following martingale: $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, and for any $n > 1$, $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(X_{n-1}, X_{n-1}^2)$ (notice, this is a conditional distribution given $X_{n-1}$).

I am looking for concentration bounds for $X_n$, which I suspect exist, based on numerical simulation.

**Additional information:**

It is easy to see that $\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = 2^{n-1}$, by induction over $n$.

The $n=1$ case is trivial. Since $X_n$ is unbiased, for any $n > 1$, $$\underset{X_n}{\mathbb{E}} \left[X_n^2 \mid X_{n-1} \right] = \underset{X_n}{\mathbb{E}} \left[(X_{n-1} + (X_n - X_{n-1}))^2 \,|\, X_{n-1} \right] = X_{n-1}^2 + \underset{X_n}{\mathbb{E}} \left[(X_n - X_{n-1})^2 \mid X_{n-1} \right] = 2 X_{n-1}^2.$$
Using this fact we get, $$\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = \underset{X_1, \ldots, X_n}{\mathbb{E}} \left[X_n^2 \right] = \underset{X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}}{\mathbb{E}} \left[ \underset{X_n}{\mathbb{E}} \left[X_n^2 \mid X_{n-1} \right] \right] = \underset{X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}}{\mathbb{E}} \left[2 X_{n-1}^2 \right] = 2 \operatorname{Var}(X_{n-1}).$$

At first glance, this might lead to the assumption that the distribution becomes less concentrated as $n$ grows, but running some simulations, it seems like the distribution actually gets more concentrated around $0$, and the growth of the variance results from the tails becoming heavier.

It is possible to state this question in a more general form, by defining $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(X_{n-1}, f(X_{n-1}))$ for any non negative function $f$. A similar question was presented in [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227556/adaptive-version-of-the-azuma-hoeffding-inequality), but the answers do not apply to this example.

This question has close ties to the method of mixtures (see e.g., Theorem 2.7 in [De la Pena et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.2233.pdf)), but as far as I understand, none of their results can be used to answer the question, the way it was formalized here.

Comment: I'd write $X_n \mid X_{n-1} \sim \mathcal{N}(X_{n-1}, X_{n-1}^2)$ rather than $X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(X_{n-1}, X_{n-1}^2).$

Comment: @moshenfeld Is the answer below sufficiently clear? If so, do you know how to accept an answer?

Comment: Thank you, @YuvalPeres. Of course, I would hope for a finite sample bound that is better than than what can be achieved using the second moment + Chebyshev or CLT + Berry–Esseen, but the answer is clear and very helpful. And now I learned how to accept an answer as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Observe that $X_n=X_{n-1}(1+Z_n)$ where $\{Z_k\}_{k \ge 1}$ are i.i.d. standard normal. Hence to analyze the asymptotic distribution of $|X_n|$, pass to logarithms, to get $$\log(|X_n|)= \log(|X_1|) +\sum_{k=2}^n \log(|1+Z_k|) \tag{$*$} \,.$$

According to Wolfram alpha,
\begin{align}
& \mu:=E\bigl[ \log(|1+Z_k|) \bigr] \\[8pt] = {} & \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(|1+z|)e^{-z^2/2} \, dz\in [-0.2085,-0.2084]  \,.
\end{align}

Thus the law of large numbers yields that  for large $n$, with high probability,
$$ \log(|X_n|) <-n/5 \quad \text{whence } |X_n|<e^{-n/5} \,.$$
This confirms the prediction of the O.P.
More precise information can be extracted from $(*)$ via the asymptotic distribution   theory for sums of i.i.d. variables [1].

[1] Petrov, Valentin V. "Sums of independent random variables."   De Gruyter, 2022.

Comment: I think you may have misplaced some absolute values in the second displayed equation.

Comment: @Thomas   Thanks you, corrected now